# How can I keep my window always zoomed?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nswindow

So I have storyboard with 2 view controller's and 1 window controller. In my subclass of `NSWindowController` I can put my window zoomed like this:

```
override func windowDidLoad() { 
    super.windowDidLoad()
    window?.zoom(self) // Or window?.setFrame(NSScreen.mainScreen()!.visibleFrame, display: true)
}
```

But when I want to change my window's content view controller, that size doesn't remain same size and I have to tell to zoom it again and that is ugly animation. How can I manage to keep my window's zoomed even if I change my window's content view controller?

UPDATE:

I manage to get it work. In my IBAction when my another window controller is zoomed, I did this when I want change content view controller.

```
secondViewController!.view.frame = contentViewController!.view.frame
contentViewController = secondViewController
```

Comment: Please attach sample app. It's not clear what and how you change it.

Comment: Ok, I manage to get it work.